# In R, what is the keyword for jumping out of a function without executing the rest of it?

Tags: function, r, return

I am wondering if there is any keyword in R for jumping out of a function without executing the rest of it. In C, Java, or Matlab, there is the keyword 'return'. But the 'return' keyword in R works different than in those languages. Here is an example,

```
myfunc = function() {
  if (TRUE) {
      return # hopefully, jump out of the function
  }
  print('the rest of the function is still executed!')
}
```

In the example, languages like Java will not execute 'the rest' when 'return' is met, while in R 'return' is only in the scope of the if statement and the rest of the functions is still executed.  In this particular example I could have added an 'else' block to achieve it but I would like to know if there is any keyword which would give similar behaviors as in Java etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you show is actually syntactically valid R code ... but you have the mistake of *not supplying a value* to `return`.  So here is a corrected version:

```
R> myfunc <- function() {
  if (TRUE) {
      return(NULL) # hopefully, jump out of the function
  }
  print('the rest of the function is still executed!')
}
myfunc <- function() {
+   if (TRUE) {
+       return(NULL) # hopefully, jump out of the function
+   }
+   print('the rest of the function is still executed!')
+ }
R> myfunc()
NULL
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found that return() would also work and return NULL as default, but I assume providing a value explicitly would be a good style. Thanks.

Comment: +1, never realized `return()` also stopped executing the function, what will save some `else` and `{ }` in my codes for sure!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
stopifnot()
```

Comment: stopifnot() is very useful but I'd accept Dirk's answer. Thanks.